# Updating material does not take affect until restart

Tags: materials

I am testing the new 2.8 build and can not get materials to update in the preview or 3D Viewport until I restart or reload the .blend

Is there a setting I need to turn on to get these to refresh automatically?

Using OSX Majave and Cycles render.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there was a bug in the Feb 15 build.  I downloaded the source from blender.org and the issue is no longer happening.